# javascript:prototype

Tags: javascript

when the new object is constructed ,The object is set up to delegate any properties which haven't been explicitly set up to its constructor's prototype. That means that we can change the prototype later, and still see the changes in the instance.

first:

```
 function Foo(){}
 foo=new Foo();
 Foo.prototype={};
 foo.constructor==Foo//true.why is this happening since construtor prototype is empty object
```

so the statement are not working as per the definition.right or wrong?
but if i do this than result is different

second:

```
 function Foo(){}
  Foo.prototype={};
 foo=new Foo();

 foo.constructor==Foo//false as aspected
```

again 
third:

```
  function Foo(){}
  Foo.prototype={};
   Foo.prototype.name="Maizere";
 foo=new Foo();

 foo.name==Maizere//true.The definition at the top is applying here,if so why the definition not working in the first: example
```

plz help with simple english.i m really getting headache.

Comment: Instead of using `constructor`, couldn't you just use `foo instanceof Foo`?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté constructor has no relation with instanceOf operator

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: That would lead to different problems in here :-/

Comment: @Bergi Really? Seems like OP is just trying to check if an instance has the same prototype of a constructor, which `instanceof` would be ideal for. Unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @OP I know these are "unrelated", however from reading your question it seems like `instanceof` was what you were looking for in case you're trying to solve an issue. In case this is more of a theoretical question about how the `constructor` property behaves, then these are unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

> why is this happening

The [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) sets the inheritance of the instance to the object that the constructor's `prototype` property currently points to. So when you do

```
function Foo() {}
var foo = new Foo;
```

it is irrelevant if someone assigns to `Foo.prototype` after that - it will not change `foo`.

- first: The inherited `constructor` property you are getting comes from the "old" prototype - an object that is initialized together with the function and having that hidden "constructor" property
- second: You are overwriting the `prototype` property with an empty object, and your `foo` (created after overwriting) inherits from that. And since empty objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, the `constructor` property now points to the `Object` function.
- third: Again, you create `foo` after overwriting the `prototype`. Since you assign a `name` property to that new object from which `foo` inherits from, you can access it on `foo` as well.

Comment: thanks for your post.But still lacks some more advance answer

Comment: but the definition says that the object is set to appoints properties and method which have not been explicitely set in its constructor prototype.so when we appoint new object in the constructor prototype that should also be appointed and tht should make the prototype empty for ever

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Visual examples usually help understanding faster so here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ8Ld/). What I didn't understand is why the instance doesn't inherit the new prototype object's constructor property.

Comment: Oh of course, when you overwrite the prototype with another object, the already created instances are kept unmodified - they inherit from the old prototype. Having a slow day today. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ8Ld/2/).

Comment: @Maizere: Which "definition" are you talking of?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a function, it comes with a property named `prototype` - an object whose `constructor` property is set to the function itself. As you may have known, JavaScript's object model is prototype based. This makes the objects you create with that function inherit all the properties of the `prototype` of its constructor function (the one you invoke with `new`) - so you should beware what `prototype` is **the moment you create the object**.

In your first case, you are just setting the `prototype` property of `Foo` to an empty object. But the original (default) `prototype` is still referenced by `foo`. That explains why the last expression evaluates to true.

By the time you create `foo` in your second case, `prototype` of `Foo` has already been set to an empty object. So virtually `foo` inherits nothing from it. The same principle applies to the third case.